# React in Azure App service - Is it possible to host frontend & backend in same App service?

Tags: reactjs, azure

I have a React project I'm pushing with github to Azure App service.
I added a small backend to my frontend project:

```
`const PORT = 8000
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const axios = require('axios')
require('dotenv').config()

const app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json('hi')

})`
```

What am I missing?
I'm very new at react, any input would be appreciated!

All working fine locally, but backend does not seem to start once pushed to App service.
I have created two separate start under scripts but no success.

I tried manipulating the scripts > build and adding && node backend.js.
That seems to hang my github action and put it into a loop.

Here is my package.json

```
`{
  "name": "argon-design-system-react",
  "version": "1.1.1",
  "description": "React version of Argon Design System by Creative Tim",
  "main": "index.js",
  "homepage": ".",
  "scripts": {
    "start:backend": "nodemon backend.js",
    "start:frontend": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "CI=false react-scripts build && gulp licenses",
    "test": "react-scripts test --passWithNoTests",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "classnames": "2.3.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "headroom.js": "0.12.0",
    "moment": "2.29.4",
    "nouislider": "14.1.1",
    "react": ">=16.0.0",
    "react-datetime": "3.1.1",
    "react-dom": ">=16.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "8.4.1",
    "sass": "1.53.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=16.0.0",
    "react-dom": ">=16.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.39.2",
    "@types/markerclustererplus": "2.1.33",
    "@types/react": "18.0.17",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "8.0.3",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "gulp-append-prepend": "1.0.9",
    "jquery": "3.6.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "typescript": "4.7.4"
  }
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- one work around would be to build the react first and the just serve the react page using the express
- Here I am serving the react app with a NodeJS Api, for that I first created and express app using `npx express-generator myapi`  then in the  `myapi`  directory I run this command `npx create-react-app react-app` to create the react app in the express app.
- now in the `react-app` directory I run the command  `npm run build`  this will build the react app now I also removed the build reference in the `.gitignore` file .

My app.js file :

```
var  createError = require('http-errors');
var  express = require('express');
var  path = require('path');
var  cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var  logger = require('morgan');
const { join } = require('path');

var  app = express();

app.use('/',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'react-app', 'build')));

app.get('/api',(req,res)=>{
    res.send({'hello':'world'});
});

module.exports = app;
```

Now I deployed this using git

react output: -
[image]

Api output: -
[image]